# Make: decide how to make target depending on files that are existing

Tags: c, makefile

I first want to build my programm with the -fprofile-arcs argument for compiler and linker. The I want to run the program to create a .gcda file for each object file and build it again with the -fbranch-probabilities option which enables profile directed optimizations (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html). So I want to do

```
make
./cov (creating .gcda files)
make clean (to avoid "nothing to be done for make")
make (now using .gcda files for optimization)
```

Currently the first compilation and generation of the .gcda files is working but the ifneq case is never reached.

```
CC= gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -pedantic
PROFFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs
OPFLAGS = -fbranch-probabilities
TARGET = cov
RM = rm
SOURCES = cov.c cov_lib.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
GCDA = $(SOURCES:.c=.gcda)

.PHONY: all clean clean_all

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

clean_all:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(GCDA)

ifneq ($(ls | grep .gcda),)
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
else
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(PROFFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(PROFFLAGS) -c $<
endif
```

if I am indenting the lines in the ifneq and else cases I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBtthtP.o: in function `main':
cov.c:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `print_mod5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

indented:

```
ifneq ($(ls | grep .gcda),)
    $(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@

    %.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPFLAGS) -c $<
else
    $(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(PROFFLAGS)

    %.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(PROFFLAGS) -c $<
endif
```

cov.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cov_lib.h"
int main (void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            printf ("%d is divisible by 3\n", i);
        if (i % 11 == 0)
            printf ("%d is divisible by 11\n", i);
        print_mod5(i);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

cov_lib.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_mod5(int n){
    if(n % 5 == 0){
        printf("mod 5\n");
    }
}
```

cov_lib.h

```
#ifndef COV_LIB_H
#define COV_LIB_H
void print_mod5(int n);
#endif
```

Comment: I would not do it like you suggest. This is completely dependent on discipline and memory of the users, and humans are really bad with that. Design your project tree and file dependencies in a way that all files exist in parallel in the end. That means, if you need different compilation/linking options, create as many different target files.

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles are not shell scripts.  This is wrong:

```
ifneq ($(ls | grep .gcda),)
```

You are checking if the value of the make variable `ls | grep .gcda` is empty or not, and it always will be, so this statement will never be true.

I suppose you wanted to write this:

```
ifneq ($(shell ls | grep .gcda),)
```

but simpler is:

```
ifneq ($(wildcard *.gcda),)
```